# Magento: Fatal error Class not found

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

I got error in custom module. I am getting error like this:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Test_log_Adminhtml_Block_Log' not found in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 491
```

How to fix this?
xml file

```
        <blocks>
        <log>
            <class>Test_log_Block</class>
        </wsalogger>
       <log_adminhtml>
            <class>Test_log_Adminhtml_Block</class>
        </log_adminhtml>
    </blocks>
```

Comment: provide complete this module code

Comment: means xml code? @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: yes xml and php code as well

Comment: updated xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please change as follow

```
    <log_adminhtml>
        <class>Test_log_Block_Adminhtml</class>
    </log_adminhtml>
```

Comment: error gone but data not displaying

Comment: That's why I am asking please provide me your full php code So Ican check